# Incomplete files download with alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have a list of 60 remote file (images) and I want to download all of them but when I try just download 15 images here my code

```
    let destination = Alamofire.Request.suggestedDownloadDestination(directory: .DocumentDirectory, domain: .UserDomainMask)

    for var i = 1; i < 61; i++ {

        Alamofire.download(.GET, "https://domain.com/folder/\(i).jpg", destination: destination)
            .progress { bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    print("Total bytes read on main queue: \(totalBytesRead)")
                }
            }
            .response { _, _, _, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Failed with error: \(error)")
                } else {
                    print("Downloaded file successfully")
                }
        }

    }
```

any idea???

Comment: Dunno what alamofire is, but it looks like you are downloading too much too fast, I would download one at a time,  I will put it in the answer so that the code is nicer

Answer (score 0):

```
func doDownload(i:int)
{
    if(i > 60)
    {
        return;
    }
    let destination = Alamofire.Request.suggestedDownloadDestination(directory: .DocumentDirectory, domain: .UserDomainMask)

    Alamofire.download(.GET, "https://domain.com/folder/\(i).jpg", destination: destination)
        .progress { bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                print("Total bytes read on main queue: \(totalBytesRead)")
            }
        }
        .response { _, _, _, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed with error: \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Downloaded file successfully")
                doDownload(i + 1); //If you only want to download on success do it here
            }
            //Otherwise doDownload(i + 1)here;
    }
}
```

Comment: @KnightOfDragon Thanks, I'll try it and let you know the results